# Python script(.py) is not running through Python.Exe

Tags: python-3.x

I've coded a python script in Spyder Anaconda IDE. The script is working fine and the Script is creating a text file and writing some information. When i am trying to run the Python Script(.py file) through python.exe It is not Executing and giving no output and a window popping up for millisecond which is not Noticeable.
I am attaching the library I am using in my Python script

```
import numpy
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
```

While Trying to run my script file in command prompt i encountered this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaN4l.png)

Comment: .py files are not meant to be run using python.exe

Comment: Add console output as text, not as image.

Comment: @CoolCloud what? Of course they are...

Comment: and also the error might be because your project is made entirely in a virtual env.

Comment: @user69453 i expected this confusion, what i meant is, .py files are not meant to be opened by double clicking it.

Comment: This is the same way wrong as the other, and nevertheless write what you mean and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute from a terminal that you had opened, python.exe will always open and close.

If you say you installed python globally you are able to write this on the command prompt:

```
python YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME.py
```

or

```
python3 YOUR_PROGRAM_NAME.py
```

obviously you need to be placed on the folder where your file is, (right click and open command prompt) or you navigate trough command, cd.... cd... etc

Comment: I tried but it is showing error. The error image I have updated in the question

Comment: The problem is because you need to install thingsa globally, when you are in IDE like conda, the program solves the importation by its own. i recommend you run pip install PACKAGE_NAME until your problem is solved.

Comment: It is showing now Import Module Error: Openpyxl Module. I tried to reinstall Openpyxl module through PIP, it is showing package already installed.